# Nested If Statements in a Function

Tags: php, if-statement

Hi so I am trying to make a function which actually detects the time and depends on date(H); shows what courses and some other info happen right now.

```
$holidays = false;
//$hour = date('H');
 $hour = "11"; //Changed it to test the code

function classes()
{
    if ($holdays == false) //Are we on holidays? No
    {
        if($hour > "9" && $hour < "21") //University working hours? yes
        {   
            if ($hour = "10") //Hour 10? classes below
            { 
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo '<th class="course-title"><a href="course.html">...</a></th>';
                    echo '<th class="course-category"><a href="">...</a></th>';
                    echo "<th>...</th>";
                    echo "<th>...</th>";
                    echo "<th>...</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
                //Another Class
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo '<th class="course-title"><a href="course.html">...</a></th>';
                    echo '<th class="course-category"><a href="">...</a></th>';
                    echo "<th>...</th>";
                    echo "<th>...</th>";
                    echo "<th>...</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
               //Another Class
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo '<th class="course-title"><a href="course.html">...</a></th>';
                    echo '<th class="course-category"><a href="">...</a></th>';
                    echo "<th>...</th>";
                    echo "<th>...</th>";
                    echo "<th>...</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            else{ //Hour not 10?
                echo "No classes right now.";
            }
        }
        else{ //Not working hours?
            echo "University closed at this time.</br>";

        }
    }
    else{ //Vacation?
            echo "University closed for vacation!";
    } 

}
```

So I setted $hour value to 11 so it will pass the first two ifs successfully and I expect that it will echo that there are no classes right now, but it returns that university is closed at this time. I may also mess up the } on the code.

PS: I know i am using to many echos I am not that experienced yet to go with strings

Comment: [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).... understanding this is a fundamental of working with functions in PHP

Comment: if ($hour = "10") should be if ($hour == "10")

Comment: Fabio == makes it accurate 10?

Comment: `$holidays` != `$holdays` your missing an `i`

Comment: @cmorrissey correct brother thanks

Comment: What is the current issue, wrong logic or code fails? This `I may also mess up the } on the code.` makes me think your page fails completely. If that is the case look at your logs.

Comment: @chris85 the point of the question is to help me fix the issue - logic has nothing wrong in my opinion I am just thinking that by messing } in this code ifs close when they should not and that affects the returning message.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by logic; your code outputs `No classes right now.` whereas you expect to get `University closed for vacation!` or some other scenario. I don't know what current expected behavior is or what you want. Variable scope will be an issue though. I also don't see where you call this function but I'll assume you are doing that..

Comment: @chris85 I am expecting to return "no classes right now" but it returns "closed for vacation". This function belongs to a functions.php file which is actually included on another page (include "functions.php";)  and the function is actually called later on that page (classes();)

Comment: looks like a switch statement would come in handy, how many `if($hour ==")` statements have you got ?

Comment: Non As i said before you only needed to use comparison `==`, you were just assigning again variable hour as 10, breaking your if condition. Check here http://codepad.org/olOjg4qc I also commented class to have a fast view of returning result. You also misspelled holiday in ur code, but for this example is not really important since a not assigned variable is equal to false, but it would be important to correct for further uses

Comment: @fabio thanks pal you're right. Function works fine. I noticed that you did also commented the last }

Comment: I commented the last closing braces because i commented the function

Comment: Please take note of @MarkBaker's comments. This will help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please take note of your variable scope. To access $holidays inside the function, declare it with global scope.

```
$holidays = false;
$hour = "11"; //Changed it to test the code

function classes()
{
    global $holidays, $hour;   // <=== HERE
    if ($holidays == false) //Are we on holidays? No
    {
      // your code here
    {
}
```

In addition, you have other errors that others have pointed out in your code.

> if ($hour = "10") should be if ($hour == "10") – Fabio

and

> $holidays != $holdays your missing an i – cmorrissey

Comment: Using `global` is never a good answer.... far better to pass the value as an argument to the function